# Software to guide a user into describing a picture

Tags: audio, images, accessibility, children, learning

I want to know whether there is any software that can be used to program an image so that the software may help you describe the image interactively by asking you questions such as "what is this?" and "where is this?".

If so, it would also be nice if such software were programmed to give sound cues to blind users.

It would be nice if the software could be used to be given to children, by giving them pictures (but also to people with learning disabilities).

The children could interact with the software, not by using their fingers, to touch the screen (but, by making, sounds with their mouth (or, perhaps, with their hands, or other part of the body, in the case of mute people).

Works this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind adding a full example based on an example picture? That would help us understand what you want. Thanks!

Comment: Should it work with any picture? For instance a picture I just took with my camera? Or is it OK if it only works with a pre-defined set of pictures chosen by the software's editor?